# Knowing a priori ProfileSessionSetting metadata member name

Tags: profile, metadata, package.xml

I use `ProfileSessionSetting` to deploy session timeout from an org to another. When I build the package.xml I have initially retrieve all the profile settings with a wildcard:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">    
    <types>
         <members>*</members>
         <name>ProfileSessionSetting</name>
    </types>
    <version>44.0</version>
</Package>
```

The files retrieved have this format name: `Analytics_Cloud_Integration_User_profileSessionSetting1434911804108.profile`

How can I know a priori this name?

Thanks

**UPDATE**
After, I opened a case to Salesforce, it has been created this [article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000349446&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1) 
As you can read,

> The string of numbers will differ every time.

So, it cannot be known a priori... this doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you can, and even if it is possible, it might not be worth it...but the `1434911804108` bit looks like a timestamp (since unix epoch).

You might try converting that and seeing if it matches any system dates for your target profile.

If it does correspond to, say, the createdDate for the profile, then you almost have your answer for knowing the profile's metadata file name. The hitch here would be that Salesforce only displays Datetimes down to the minute.

A normal soql query for the profile would allow you to get the timestamp, but only down to the second. If it turns out that the file name uses milliseconds in the timestamp, then you're likely out of luck.